# What can node.js do that php cannot and vice-versa?

Tags: php, node.js

I have been developing Web Applications using WAMP stack. I use javascript jQuery extensively and want to start learning node.js but what particular problems can node.js address that i cant do in php or what extra advantages would node.js provide me in respect to other server side languages. I am also interested in knowing its limitations to help me decide what and how much can be achieved using it.

Comment: Perhaps it'd be better to ask about individual cases.

Comment: one frequently mentioned advantage is that you can share code between client (jQuery) and server (node), because they both use Javascript. Applies mostly to "model classes" and validation logic.

Comment: networking glue, websockets & javascript code re-use. Really though you should be asking "What can PHP do, node.js can't do?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of thoughts on node.js vs PHP... some are just my opinions...

node.js Advantages

- Better evented/concurrency model for high traffic applications
- Code re-use between client/server
- Pretty much everything is open source and available on github
- Cleaner/bare bones, closer to the bare metal - only include what you need *(my opinion)*

node.js Disadvantages

- You will have to learn how to code in an evented way instead of a traditional linear way
- less frameworks/technologies available than PHP, many are less mature
- Less known/accepted if you are working on commercial/government projects (even though its very popular, PHP is more "acceptable" to a lot of end users/clients)
- Calculation intensive operations can block the server so you have to be a bit careful
- You will want to use a proxy server (nginx) if you set up a node.js server

Comment: Even though we have less "frameworks/technologies" then PHP I doubt they aren't better. All I hear about PHP frameworks is they are all horrible.

Comment: @Raynos Ok so please make (show me) a very reliable, mature, stable, secure Nodejs frameworks for CMS platforms like Drupal, Wordpress. And again the Ecommerce frameworks like Magento, Zencart?